# Confused on where to store / synchronize Angular state between components

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm coming from a React (/Vue) background, and am just starting with an Angular (6) project, but I'm a bit confused on how to organize things. I hope someone can help out.

I have a Component (let's call it `Microwave`). `Microwave` can do several things, and has properties like `temperature`. According to Angular docs i defined `@Input` and `@Output` for this property.

Now I have a second (GUI) component to control `Microwave`, e.g. `MicrowaveControls`. At this point I'm confused on how to set up the communication between the two. I have a few strategies:

- Pass one of the components as an input to the other. E.g. I pass the `Microwave` instance to `MicrowaveControls`. Now I can show the input field in `MicrowaveControls` like `{{microwave.temperature}}`. I can change the value with `microwave.temperature = 100`, the problem now though that changes are not reflected in the `MicrowaveControls`, it doesn't update.
- Have a copy of the `temperature` property in `MicrowaveControls`. I can listen to the events emitted by `Microwave` to synchronize the two values. Problem here is that there are now two copies of what should be the same value, which might lead to bugs etc.
- Make some kind of Service that is injected into both components that stores the (shared) properties. This approach seems to me as the best option currently, though my problem with it is that it requires extra overhead and sort of breaks the stand-alone ability of my `Microwave` component.

What is the best approach here? I hope I provided enough information!

Comment: We use a service in that scenario.  Obligatory link -> https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service  and then wrap it all up into a module.

Comment: How would you solve it in React? Would `MicrowaveControls` be somewhere inside `Microwave`?

Answer (score 0):

The Angular Docs have a very good overview for component interaction. Sounds like you want to use an event emitter.

https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-listens-for-child-event

edit: Using events is generally the best practice for parent child relationships but an injectable service declared at the root like you mentioned is good way to manage state between to components that don't have a parent child relationship.

Answer (score 0):

When you are coming from react, you might have a redux background.

When you have a complex client state to maintain, also consider the library [ngrx](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/README.md), which is a redux inspired library from Google